# roscore: libconsole_bridge.so.0.2: cannot open shared object file

Tags: ros, beagleboneblack, wheezy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have ROS (Ros_Comm) installed on my [beaglebone black with debian wheezy](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Debian).
While running roscore I get:

```
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/rosout/rosout: error while loading shared libraries: libconsole_bridge.so.0.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

While I have `libconsole-bridge-dev` installed.
While installing that I got the message:

```
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libconsole_bridge.so.0.2.
```

And nothing failed.

But in the rosout file :

```
libconsole_bridge.so.0.2 => not found is stated.
```

Does someone know how I can fix this, I think because `libconsole` is located at `/usr/local/lib`.

I tried editting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/opt/ros/indigo/lib:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf:/usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf`, but that doesnt seem to help.

And I cant seem to edit the rosout file.

Greetings

Kenavera

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224100/roscore:-libconsole_bridge.so.0.2:-cannot-open-shared-object-file/) by [Kenavera](https://answers.ros.org/users/25226/kenavera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2016-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well the

> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ros/indigo/lib:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf:/usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf

did fix it. Only the system was durping or, so. Now it works perfectly.

---

Originally posted by [Kenavera](https://answers.ros.org/users/25226/kenavera/) with karma: 56 on 2016-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2